# How do I exclude a block from -WhatIf processing?

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a Powershell cmdlet that needs to execute a command and store its stderr output to a temporary file for later processing. This output lists COM ports that the cmdlet may use later.

```
# mostly side-effect-free information gathering
$info = [IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
info-gather.exe 2>$info
Get-Content $info | ForEach-Object {
    # processing
}
Remove-Item $info

# serious things with serious side effects start here
```

I would like this cmdlet to implement `-WhatIf` since it will have non-trivial side effects. However, the `-WhatIf` behavior takes over the `info-gather.exe` command and it is simply never executed. Instead, it prints:

> What if: Performing the operation "Output to File" on target "temp\path\to\tmp78A4.tmp"

Because this command is never executed, the inner processing doesn't happen either, and the rest of my cmdlet that has actual side effects isn't executed because it doesn't know which ports to use, making `-WhatIf` largely useless.

How can I bypass `-WhatIf` for this block without overriding it in the rest of the cmdlet?

Comment: I'm curious if between `$info = [IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()` and 
`info-gather.exe 2>$info` (and you were to sleep or pause for a moment) if the temporary file **actually exists** when also sent the `-WhatIf` switch.

Comment: @gravity, I'm not sure I understand your comment. `GetTempFileName()` creates a file and returns its name, so that file is guaranteed to exist when `2>$info` happens (but `GetTempFileName` is guaranteed to not return the name of another file that already exists).

Comment: Do this cmdlet have `[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]`? How do have this set up to support `-WhatIf`?

Comment: @Matt, yes, this cmdlet has `SupportsShouldProcess=$true`. Later in the cmdlet (after "serious things with serious side effects"), I use `$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `try...finally` to set and then reset the [`$WhatIfPreference` variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847796.aspx).

```
$script:oldWhatIfPrefernence = $WhatIfPreference
try {
    $WhatIfPreference = $false

    $info = [IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
    info-gather.exe 2>$info
    Get-Content $info | ForEach-Object {
        # processing
    }
    Remove-Item $info
} finally {
    $WhatIfPreference = $script:oldWhatIfPreference
}
```

If you weren't using the `2>` redirection, there is another way. You can pass the `-WhatIf` switch explicitly to many cmdlets and override `-WhatIf` for just that part.

```
Remove-Item $info -WhatIf:$false
```

Though, [zneak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36292606/2392683) that doesn't involve a temporary file is pretty elegant too.

Comment: It may need to replace `$WhatIfPreference` at some point in the `try` block, no?

Comment: Doh. Fixed. Thanks, @zneak.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to "redirect" stderr to stdout. Doing this, Powershell appends error records to the standard output, which can be converted to regular strings using `Out-String`. In my case (YMMV depending on the program), the first error record says "there was an error with this program" and the second error record is the actual, full stderr output. This is also simplified by the fact that the command doesn't write anything to the standard output, so there's no filtering to do there.

I was able to change the foreach loop to use this:

```
((info-gather.exe 2>&1)[1] | Out-String) -split "[`r`n]" | foreach-object
```

Since this does not write to a file, `-WhatIf` no longer overrides it.

There is probably a simpler and cleaner way to do this (for instance, if there was a way to pipe stderr to `Out-String` directly).