# How NOT to propagate -WhatIf and -Confirm?

Tags: powershell

It seems the default behaviour of Powershell is to propagate -WhatIf and -Confirm to all functions called from within a function that was called with -WhatIf or -Confirm.

But what if (pun intended) I don't want that ? What if all I want is to protect a bit of code that performs an actual change on my system and not the rest of my code ?

Here is an example:

```
function Set-Something {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess = $true, ConfirmImpact = 'Medium')]
    [OutputType([string])] 

    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string] $ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    )

    Process {
        New-Item -Path "beforeChange" -Type File | Out-Null
        Remove-Item -Path "beforeChange" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

        # Here is the bit of code that needs to be "protected"
        if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($ComputerName, "Do something")) {
            # Actually do something on $ComputerName
            New-Item -Path "inChange" -Type File | Out-Null
            Remove-Item -Path "inChange" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        }

        New-Item -Path "afterChange" -Type File | Out-Null
        Remove-Item -Path "afterChange" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
}

"-"*50 + "Set-Something -WhatIf" + "-"*50 
Set-Something -WhatIf
"-"*50 + "Set-Something -Confirm" + "-"*50 
Set-Something -Confirm
```

The Set-Something function only performs system-altering stuff in the protected bit. It also uses temporary files, but New-Item and Remove-Item shouldn't trigger WhatIf or Confirm. Unfortunately that's not how it works:

```
--------------------------------------------------Set-Something -WhatIf--------------------------------------------------
What if: Performing the operation "Create File" on target "Destination: C:\Users\GO7\beforeChange".
What if: Performing the operation "Do something" on target "GEOCED".
What if: Performing the operation "Create File" on target "Destination: C:\Users\GO7\afterChange".
```

I could add `-WhatIf:$false -Confirm:$false` to each and every function that supports ShouldProcess but that would be tedious.

So What I've done so far is :

1. save the $WhatIfPreference and $ConfirmPreference at the top of my function
2. reset those preferences to their default value
3. restore the saved preferences before the protected block
4. reset the preferences again inside the block and outside the block

Like so:

```
function Set-Something2 {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess = $true, ConfirmImpact = 'Medium')]
    [OutputType([string])] 

    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string] $ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    )

    Begin {
        # Save the ShouldProcess parameters for later use
        $WhatIfPref = $WhatIfPreference
        $ConfirmPref = $ConfirmPreference

        # Reset ShouldProcess parameters to their default value
        $WhatIfPreference = 0
        $ConfirmPreference = 'High'
    }

    Process {
        New-Item -Path "beforeChange" -Type File | Out-Null
        Remove-Item -Path "beforeChange" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

        # We restore the previously saved ShouldProcess parameters just before the "protected" bit of code
        $WhatIfPreference = $WhatIfPref
        $ConfirmPreference = $ConfirmPref

        # Here is the bit of code that needs to be "protected"
        if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($ComputerName, "Do something")) {
            # Inside the protected bit, we reset ShouldProcess parameters to their default value
            $WhatIfPreference = 0
            $ConfirmPreference = 'High'

            # Actually do something on $ComputerName
            New-Item -Path "inChange" -Type File | Out-Null
            Remove-Item -Path "inChange" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        }

        # After the protected bit, we reset ShouldProcess parameters to their default value
        $WhatIfPreference = 0
        $ConfirmPreference = 'High'

        New-Item -Path "afterChange" -Type File | Out-Null
        Remove-Item -Path "afterChange" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
}

"-"*50 + "Set-Something2 -WhatIf" + "-"*50 
Set-Something2 -WhatIf
"-"*50 + "Set-Something2 -Confirm" + "-"*50 
Set-Something2 -Confirm
```

The result is as I want it:

```
--------------------------------------------------Set-Something2 -WhatIf--------------------------------------------------
What if: Performing the operation "Do something" on target "GEOCED".
--------------------------------------------------Set-Something2 -Confirm--------------------------------------------------

Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing the operation "Do something" on target "GEOCED".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

But is that how I'm supposed to do it ? I don't find it very elegant...

Comment: `$ConfirmPreference` and `$WhatIfPreference` are variables, so they obey variable scoping rules. (If that's what you are asking?)

Comment: I fail to see how variable scoping is going to help here ? Even if I change the scope to local, new-item and remove-item will still trigger the confirm prompt and files wille not get created/deleted if whatif was passed to the function.

Comment: It's not a matter of what "helps". It's a matter of understanding how it works. The behavior you observe is by design.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, by design, Powershell propagates those 2 preferences from a caller function to all callees. But I don't care about New-Item asking me to confirm, I only care about a specific block of code in my function. So I guess the way I did it in Set-Something2 is the right way of circumventing this automatic propagation feature ?

Comment: "But I don't care about New-Item asking me to confirm" - so specify `-Confirm:$false` where you specifically don't want it to do so.

Comment: Yep, but as I said, adding -WhatIf:$false -Confirm:$false to each and every function that supports ShouldProcess is really tedious for complex functions that call numerous built-in Powershell functions or custom functions in the same file or in other modules.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be about scopes. Run this and read the docs:

```
help about_Scopes
```

You can change a preference variable (e.g., `$ConfirmPreference`) in a scope, but that doesn't affect its value in parent scopes. Here's a short example:

```
PS C:\Scripts> $ConfirmPreference
High
PS C:\Scripts> Get-Content .\Test-Preference.ps1
$ConfirmPreference = "Low"
$ConfirmPreference
PS C:\Scripts> .\Test-Preference.ps1
Low
PS C:\Scripts> $ConfirmPreference
High
```

As you can see from this short example, the preference variable automatically reverts to its previous value once the scope (i.e., the script) terminates.

If you want to execute a new scope within the current scope, you can invoke a scriptblock using the `&` operator. Example:

```
$ConfirmPreference

# execute a scriptblock (create new scope, change preference variable)
& {
  $ConfirmPreference = "Low"
  $ConfirmPreference
}

$ConfirmPreference
```

If you put the above lines in a script file and run it, the output will be:

```
High
Low
High
```

Comment: I don't think we understand each other ! This is not a question that can be solved with scopes. The closest question I found was this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36291735/how-do-i-exclude-a-block-from-whatif-processing?rq=1 IMHO, Powershell default's behaviour should be to **not propagate** WhatIf and Confirm. I really don't see any case where "implicit propagation" is helpful. I'd much rather use explicit propagation wherever I need it. In the end, Set-Something2 is probably the way to go...

Comment: See my expanded answer - you can invoke a scriptblock in the current scope to create a new scope. You can then set the preference variables how you want. But remember that they are variables, so they obey the scoping rules.

Comment: Yep, your solution is basically what I did in  `Set-Something2` : save the preference in another variable and reset them to their default value, in order to control `-Confirm` and `-WhatIf` and prevent them from being all over the place. But I have to restore them every time I call `$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess(...)` otherwise my cmdlet will not support `-Confirm` and `-Whatif`. It's ugly but it works!

Comment: Wait... It seems `$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess(...)` doesn't check the preferences variables so I don't need to restore the variables before calling it. All I need is to reset both variables at the top of my cmdlet and that's it ! Much nicer !

Comment: Now I understand your confusion @Bill : my assumptions regarding how `$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess(...)` works was wrong. I thought it relied on both preference variables or `if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('WhatIf'))` but it seems to work whether I reset those preference variables or if I do `$PSBoundParameters.Remove('WhatIf')`

Comment: Well I was wrong again. If I reset both preference variables at the start of my function but don't restore them before `if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess(...)`, then implicit propagation will not work anymore. For example: `& {$WhatIfPreference = $true ; Test-ShouldProcessResetOnly}` will not trigger WhatIf and will actually execute the protected block

Answer (score 0):

To work around this on specific functions where I didn't want `-WhatIf` to be passed down I set it explicitly to `$false`.

For example from an Azure script which needs to set a subscription context so later read-only queries work properly:

```
Set-AzContext -Subscription $Subscription -WhatIf:$false
```

This prevents `Set-AzContext` from inheriting the `-WhatIf` from my main script but still allows me to selectively use `$PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess()` later on for more dangerous changes.